# Webpage reloading in every form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem of page reloading.

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return commentForm()">
     <input type="text" id="text">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
     <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="txt2">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function commentForm() {
     var x = document.getElementById('check').checked;
     var y = document.getElementById('text').value;
     if (y == null || y == "") {
          alert('please enter some value');
          return false; 
     }
     if (x == false) {
          alert('Please check the checkbox')
          return false;
     }
     else {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += document.getELementById('text').value + "<br>";
          return true;
     }
}
```

My problem is that when i submit the page it is reloading instead of copying the text.
Please help me with that.

Comment: Can I have my virus in blue? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry guys. I am new to stack overflow. Really sorry. Please help me with that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function commentForm() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('check').checked;
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    if (!text) {
        alert('please enter some value');
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkbox) {
        alert('Please check the checkbox');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += text + "<br>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return commentForm()">
     <input type="text" id="text">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
     <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="txt2">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you want the page not to be redirected you can use the `return false` in the `else` statement.

Comment: I'd suggest using descriptive variable names. Also you could say `innerHTML += y` instead of getting the element again, since you assigned it to the variable `var y`, which is where descriptive variable naming would have come in handy.

Comment: @jdgregson I just copied the code from the owner for helping him in his prob. I know it. You can explain it to Advaith.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I changed the button from a submit input to just a button input so that it only runs the script. You don't want the form to submit, that requires a reload of the page to "submit" the form to the sever. Also you need to get the `value` from the text input:

`document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += document.getElementById('text').value + "<br>`

But since you already put that value into `var text` you can just reuse that variable. Additionally you weren't checking if if the checkbox was checked because it was looking at the variable `x` for both inputs. Try running this:

```js
function commentForm() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById('check').checked;
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    if (!text) {
        alert('please enter some value');
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkBox) {
        alert('Please check the checkbox')
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += text + "<br>";
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
    <input type="button" value="Comment" class="txt2" onclick="return commentForm()">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But it was a mistake on my code written in here. I wrote it correctly on my original web page. Changing from <form onSubmit="commentForm()"> to <input type="button" onClick="commentForm()"> will use the return false or true??

Comment: What do you mean to do with the return code? The `commentForm()` function is returning `true` when it appends the text to `demo`, but there is nothing that uses that return code after the button is clicked on the form.

Comment: This is just a short form of my original code. On my original i need to use `return` because it is large in code.

Comment: Well I guess I'd have to see how it's used in the rest of the code to understand. But I added a return in the `onClick` above and it seems to work. Try it in the rest of the code and see if it's good?

Comment: I will give my html. It is only having basic kind of things please don't brag me. [link](http://www112.zippyshare.com/v/nlg1WYK8/file.html)

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't worked with forms and the conventional submit methods in a while. But I'm not sure what the original problem is then. The page you provided works as I would expect: it prevents the submit until all of the requirements are met.